# Can we prove that $\lim \|X^T A X\| / \|X\| = 0$ as $\|X\|\to 0$ for all norms?

Tags: matrices, limits, normed-spaces, matrix-calculus

Suppose $X$ and $A$ are two matrices of compatible dimensions.

Is it possible to prove that
$$
\lim_{\|X\|\to 0} \frac{\|X^T A X\|}{\|X\|} = 0,
$$

where:

- A is squared, X may not be squared.
- The norms can be any norm (Frobenius, induced, max, etc).
- The norms in the numerator and denominator can be different.
- The submultiplicative property $\|AB\|\le \|A\| \|B\|$ may not be satisfied.
- The limit is taken for any sequence $\{X_n\}$ whose norm goes to zero.

I can do it for some cases, but not in general. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems not, to me. If, for example, $X$ and $A$ are square matrices, and $A=(X^T)^{-1}$, then the ratio is always $1$ so the limit is as well.

Comment: @MPW $A$ is fixed, $X$ goes to zero in norm.

Comment: for which cases can you do it? Do you know that any two norms on a finite dimensional vector space are equivalent?

Comment: (equivalence of norms implies in particular that $ ||AB||\le c||A||||B||$ for some fixed $c$ as soon as you have such an inequalitiy for one particular norm)

Comment: @Thomas: Thank you! didn't know about the equivalence. I think it solves it because $\|X^TAX\|\le c\|X^TA\| \|X\|$, where $\|X\|$ will cancel the denominator and the other goes to zero.

Comment: Maybe. You have to be careful with the dimensions. Equivalence is, of course, only available in a given dimension. You have to check the details. I'm to lazy right now, sorry ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this follows from homogeneity: for any two norms, and for any positive scalar $\lambda $
$$ \frac{\|(\lambda X)^T A (\lambda X)\| }{|||\lambda X|||} = \lambda   \frac{\|X^T A X\| }{|||X|||}  \tag{1} $$

Indeed, let $K = \{X: |||X||| =1\} $. Since this is a compact set, the function $X\mapsto \|X^T A X\|$ attains its maximum on it, let this maximum be $M$. The property (1)  yields
$$
|||X||| = \lambda \implies \frac{\|X^T A X\|}{|||X|||} \le M\lambda
$$ 
or simply put, 
$$\frac{\|X^T A X\|}{|||X|||} \le M \, |||X|||$$
The claim follows.